# change the search term to lower case in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, search

I am creating a search function for the product but I have a problem that, my product name is to capitalize on the first letter, for example, I have the product name `Lemon` if I search for `lemon` it will say `the product does not exist`. How can I `change it to be searchable by uppercase or lowercase`

Here is the product list page

```
const ProductList = ({
  products,
  searchTerm,
  loading,
  fetchProductRequest,
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductRequest();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const [sortAndFilter, setSortAndFilter] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let results = [...products];

    results = results.filter(product => {
      return product.name.includes(searchTerm)
        || searchTerm.includes(product.name)
        || searchTerm.includes(product.price);
    });

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Loading />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        {!!sortAndFilter && sortAndFilter.length > 0 ? (
          sortAndFilter.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <ProductItem
                key={index}
                image={product.image}
                name={product.name}
                price={parseInt(product.price)}
              />
            );
          })
        ) :
          (
            <h4 className="center-title">Product list is empty!</h4>
          )}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

My structure is like this

Answer (score 0):

See, your search code should be correct, the only thing I can guess is you should convert your search term to lower/upper case before while matching.

e.g.:

```
searchInput = 'I AM searched'

searchTerm = searchInput.toLowerCase()
```

or `toUpperCase` etc

and same also for the values stored in database etc

because

`input.toLowercase() === stored.toLowerCase()`
this will never have case problem

Comment: I don't clear yet about your answer could you please get me more detail about it. maybe apply my code above in here to let me more understand

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do from Frontend. The matter is from backend the search API is searching by case sensitive or non case-sensitive. The logic should be handle from the backend.
The current behaviour as you described is that the backend is searching by case-sensitive, so if you want to search by non case-sensitive you need to change the backend (the search API).
If you are search from Frontend the you can use Regular Expression to match with insensitive case

```
const searchReg = new RegExp('[' + searchTerm + ']', 'gi')//the 'i' modifier for insensitive case. 'g': to find all the matches.
results = results.filter(product => 
  return searchReg.test(product.name) || searchReg.test(product.price));
```

Comment: At the moment I am searching in frontend, not backend here so what can I change the code in `searchTerm` and `prod.name` to Lower case above before comparing it. Like this ```results = results.filter(product => {
      const searchInput = searchTerm.toLowerCase();```

Comment: I saw it but it does not work for me, it does not show product before in the UI after I input search value then all product is shown not just 1 product I input on the search form

Comment: I mean first of all my product is show all list of products in UI, but after that, when I input the search term it will display just that product has that name I have search regardless of the case, it still shows the product.